# Como limpar sessões temporárias em Apache

Tags: php, apache

Tenho um servidor Apache o qual está armazenando as sessões dos usuários em arquivos em uma pasta.

php.ini

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Porém na pasta "/tmp" está com vários arquivos e está me causando alguns problemas. Posso comentar o session.save_handler? Irá interferir no uso das sessões no site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para remover os arquivos e subdiretórios do diretório:

```
cd /tmp
rm -rf *
```

Comment: E excluindo os arquivos de sessão temporários vai interferir no uso no site?

Comment: Bom, interferir no uso do site é um termo meio complexo (interferir em qual sentido?), acredito que não por ser uma pasta de arquivos temporários, você pode mover os arquivos e se não mudar nada deleta.